# jquery/css - Pop out animation

Tags: jquery, css

I'm creating an animated landing page using jQuery.[image]

In the animation when the mouse is over a section of the image (which is sliced),
it pops out. Up till now I have been able to do this only if I set the sections' positions to absolute. If they are not positioned absolute, they move once I enlarge and move out one of the sections.

Is there any way to get this effect without seting position to absolute?

Thank you!

**Edit:** This is the code I'm using

```
$(".block").mousemove(function () {
    $(this).css("z-index", "1010");
    $(this).stop().animate({
        "width": "170px",
        "height": "400px",
        "top": "-12px",
        "left": "-13px"
    }, {
        duration: 300,
        easing: "swing",
        queue: true
    });
});

$(".block").mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        "width": "149px",
        "height": "374px",
        "top": "0px",
        "left": "0px"
    }, {
        duration: 500,
        easing: "swing",
        queue: true,
        complete: function () {
            $(this).css("z-index", "1000");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: can you provide a second simulated screnshot of what you're trying to achieve? Also, any code so far to compare?

Comment: @Brian Scott - I edited the post and added the code I use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution to your question could be this:

Right now each image is placed beside one another, right? Instead, try placing just white blocks beside one another as the placeholders to keep the dimensions and then place the images inside those boxes.

I don't know your actual html code, but I can see you have six blocks in your example picture.

Below I have tried to set up a hover event on a very simple html box structure from the script you gave. In your script you had something about the `z-index` value and something to happen when `complete`. I have deleted that, since I couldn't get the meaning of it or see it work with `stop()`, but you might edit this to match your wishes.

Also I don't use much `class` or `id`, but that might be needed at a larger page.
**EDIT**: Make sure your divs have the exact same dimensions as the image they contain.

**HTML**

```
<div id="blocks">

    <!--The divs are the blocks - the imgs are the content-->
    <div><img src="block1.png"></div>
    <div><img src="block2.png"></div>
    <div><img src="block3.png"></div>
    <div><img src="block4.png"></div>
    <div><img src="block5.png"></div>
    <div><img src="block6.png"></div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div#blocks { /*The wrapping box*/
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    /*Remember to add paddings, margins, borders etc.*/
}

div#blocks div { /*Creating the blocks*/
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
    width: 50px;
}

/*The images now fill nothing at all*/
div#blocks img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$("div#blocks img").hover(

    function(){ /*On mousein*/
    $(this).stop().animate({

        "width": $(this).width() + 20, /*Enlarging by 20 x 20px*/
        "height": $(this).width() + 20,
        "top": "-10px", /*Keeping image centeret*/
        "left": "-10px",
        "z-index": "10"

        }, {

        duration: 300,
        easing: "swing",
        queue: true

        });
    },
    function(){ /*On mouseout*/
    $(this).stop().animate({

        "width": $(this).width(), /*Returning to original size*/
        "height": $(this).width(),
        "top": "0px", /*Keeping image centeret*/
        "left": "0px",
        "z-index": "0"

        }, {

        duration: 500,
        easing: "swing",
        queue: true

        });
    }

);
```

PS: Untested, but quite simple. You can give it a try.

Comment: I basiclly want the div I hover on to stretch vertically and horizontally and overlap the slices on both sides of it.

Comment: Okay, that might be done by having a just white placeholder div with the `<img>` placed on top of it. The placeholder div will never change its size, but the img that are placed at the same coordinates can be enlarged or moved by jQuery.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm sorry, I don't follow. Can you please edit the answer and elaborate?